# c++ virtual inheritance difference

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

Given two classes with a common virtual base class:

```
class Base {};

class Derived1 : public virtual Base {};

class Derived2 : public virtual Base {};
```

Is there any difference between these two further derived classes?:

- ```
  class Derived3 : public virtual  Base, public Derived1, public Derived2 {};
  ```
- ```
  class Derived3 : public Derived1, public Derived2 {};
  ```

The first also derives directly from the virtual base class, but I think that has no effect, because it's shared with `Derived1` and `Derived2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They say the same thing. The only difference is that if you removed `public Derived1` and `public Derived2` from both definitions of `Derived3`, the first one would still inherit from `Base` and the second one would not.

EDIT: I haven't thought carefully about whether there is some weird cross-cast situation where the two would also behave differently, although I don't think there is.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between those examples.

But in a more complicated scenario, directly inheriting an otherwise inherited virtual base might change the order of construction / destruction of the base class subobjects.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any difference in object layout because the intention of virtual inheritance is to avoid having two copies of `Base` (or three copies in case 1).

So all the difference is in your intentions and really readability of the code.